# Receiving error "Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string" at @wire (MessageContext)

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-message-service

I am getting an error while publishing message from one web Component:
[error = TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string at], it occurs while receiving MessageContext using  @wire(MessageContext)
mContext;

console says mContext value = Symbol(MessageContext_43ee57fb_fbb4_4cf1_bd78_c45358de67cd)

**Sample Code:**

```
    import {publish,MessageContext,APPLICATION_SCOPE} from 'lightning/messageService';

    import publishMM from '@salesforce/messageChannel/publishMajorModel__c';

    @wire(MessageContext)
    mContext; // **Here it is getting into Error...**

     callScreen2(event) {
    this.showScreen2Component = true;
    this.isVisible = false;      ..
    const payload = {mmValue : this.selectedValue}
    publish(this.mContext, publishMM, payload);
}
```

Comment: Can you add a sample code to help reproduce it?

Comment: This kind of error occurs when you are attempting to coerce a `Symbol` into a `String`: https://jsfiddle.net/Lt9qn2r5/.